# how to write the sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like

```
ID      USER_ID    type
1         1         2
2         1         1
3         3         3
4         3         1
5         6         2 
6         6         3
```

and i want to get the sum of all user_id = 1 and user_id =3
and every type sum in user_id = 1 and user_id =3 ,it can be two sql
the result is

```
sum
 4

type sum
 1    2   
 2    1
 3    1
```

Comment: I'm sure you know already.  But you have to post the SQL that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function you needed to achieve the result is `Count()` not `SUM()` function

For first result

```
select count(*) as sum from user1 where user_id in(1,3)
```

For second result you need to select type also and it should be grouped

```
 select type, count(*) as sum from user1 where user_id in(1,3)
    group by type
```

[Fiddle for second](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05680/5) you can check the first one also there by taking the query

Next time post your effort. Guess you are naive to sql.

Comment: thanks i have tried to write complex sql like:select d.remote_scale_name,d.remote_scale_id,e.remote_scale_id,e.scaleCount from test_scale d inner join (SELECT count(a.remote_scale_id) as scaleCount,a.remote_scale_id FROM test_user_scale_result a
     inner join (
               SELECT user_id FROM consult.en_org_user_department d inner join (select department_id from en_org_user_department  where user_id = 21) f on d.department_id = f.department_id
          ) b on a.user_id = b.user_id group by a.remote_scale_id) e on d.remote_scale_id = e.remote_scale_id;

Comment: ok..next time include  what ever you tried in the question even it is giving error or not logically correct else we will think you are simply asking for an answer with out effort